# Ошибка SyntaxError: can't assign to function call в задаче на площадь

Tags: python-3.x

```
Type=input()
if Type=='треугольник': a=float(input()), b=float(input()), c=float(input()), p=(a+b+c)/2, s=(p*((p-a)*(p-b)*(p-c)))**0.5, print(s)
elif Type=='прямоугольник': 
    a=float(input()), b=float(input()), s=a*b, print(s)
else:
    r=float(input()), s=3.14*(r**2), print(s)
```

Comment: Разделитель команд в одной строке - точка с запятой. А вообще не пишите так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема здесь:

```
a=float(input()), b=float(input()), c=float(input()), p=(a+b+c)/2, s=(p*((p-a)*(p-b)*(p-c)))**0.5, print(s)
```

Вы применили запятую (`,`), а не точку с запятой (`;`) для отделения отдельных команд. Это бы возможно было на языках C/C++, где запятая используется другим образом, но в Питоне запятая в вашем контексте приводит к синтаксической ошибке, потому что часть

```
a=float(input()), b
```

ожидает присвоить переменной `a` *кортеж* - что-то как `a = 5, 1, 3`.

Примените точку с запятой, или - гораздо лучше - напишите блок команд за двоеточием как отдельные строки программы (со соответствующими отступами):

```
if Type=='треугольник': 
    a=float(input())
    b=float(input())
    c=float(input())
    p=(a+b+c)/2
    s=(p*((p-a)*(p-b)*(p-c)))**0.5
    print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nameFigure = input("Для расчета площади введите название геометрической фигуры: ")
Для расчета площади введите название геометрической фигуры: треугольник

if nameFigure == 'треугольник':
    a, b, c = [float(i) for i in input("Для расчета пл.треугольника введите через пробел длины сторон(a b c) : ").split() ]
    p = (a + b + c) / 2
    s = (p * ((p-a) * (p-b) * (p-c))) ** 0.5
elif nameFigure=='прямоугольник':
    a, b = [float(i) for i in input("Для расчета пл.прямоугольника введите через пробел длины сторон(a b) : ").split() ]
    s = a * b
else:
    r = float(input("Для расчета пл.круга введите радиус : "))
    s = 3.14 * (r ** 2)

print(s)


Для расчета пл.треугольника введите через пробел длины сторон(a b c) : 12 12 12
62.353829072479584
```